# List of symbols and abbreviations just as two columns

Tags: lists

I would like to make a list of symbols and abbreviations without using any special packages like nomencl and alike. What I would like is just left-aligned two columns once for the symbols and one for the abbreviations.

Should I start with the following?

```
\begin{flalign*}
Symbol_1 &: Meaning of Symbol_1 \\
Symbol_2 &: Meaning of Symbol_2
:
:
\end{flalign*}
```

Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Would the list be longer than a single page (and require being broken across it)?

Comment: Hi Werner, yes, I think four or five pages

Comment: Then use a `longtable` (see my answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a list. With the help of `enumitem` package, you define a new list `abbrv`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\chaptermark{List of Abbreviations}

\begin{abbrv}
\item[ADL]                   Activities of Daily Life
\item[AST]                   Alternate Step Test
\item[BMI]                   Body Mass Index
\item[CSFT]                  Cross Step moving on Four Stops
\item[DBN]                   Dynamic Bayesian Networks
\item[DFRAC]                 Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart
\item[EMG]                   Electromyography
\item[FEUP]                  Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto
\item[FPRI]                  Fall Prediction and Risk Index
\item[FR]                    Fall Probability
\item[FRI]                   Fall Risk Index
\item[GDP]                   Gross Domestic Product
\item[GUGT]                  Get-Up-ang-Go Test
\item[LABIOMEP]              Laboratório de Biomecânica do Porto
\item[MEMs]                  Micro-Electromechanics
\item[MTC]                   Minimum Toe Clearance
\item[PCA]                   Principal Components Analysis
\item[PPA]                   Physiological Profile Assessment
\item[PPP]                   Purchasing Power Parities
\item[SMWT]                  Six Meter Walking Test
\item[STRATIFY]              Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients
\item[STST]                  Sit-To-Stand Test
\item[STST5]                 Sit-To-Stand Test with 5 repetitions
\item[SVM]                   State Vector Machine
\item[SWHSA]                 Smart Wearable Health Systems and Applications
\item[TUGT]                  Timed Up-and-Go Test
\item[USB]                   Universal Serial Bus
\item[USUST]                 Unstructured and Unsupervised Test
\item[WEFAPS]                Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System
\item[WHO]                   World Health Organization
\end{abbrv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package, along with the `longtable` environment to do this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\chaptermark{List of Abbreviations}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.37}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l @{\hspace{5mm}} l }%p{0.85\linewidth}

ADL                 &  Activities of Daily Life\\
AST                 &    Alternate Step Test\\
BMI                 &  Body Mass Index\\
CSFT                &    Cross Step moving on Four Stops\\
DBN                 &  Dynamic Bayesian Networks\\
DFRAC               &  Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
EMG                 &  Electromyography\\
FEUP                &  Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto\\
FPRI                &  Fall Prediction and Risk Index\\
FR                  &  Fall Probability\\
FRI                 &    Fall Risk Index\\
GDP                 &  Gross Domestic Product\\
GUGT                &  Get-Up-ang-Go Test\\
LABIOMEP        &  Laboratório de Biomecânica do Porto\\
MEMs                &    Micro-Electromechanics\\
MTC                 &    Minimum Toe Clearance\\
PCA                 &  Principal Components Analysis\\
PPA                 &    Physiological Profile Assessment\\
PPP                 &  Purchasing Power Parities\\
SMWT                &  Six Meter Walking Test\\
STRATIFY        &  Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
STST                &    Sit-To-Stand Test\\
STST5               &  Sit-To-Stand Test with 5 repetitions\\
SVM                 &  State Vector Machine\\
SWHSA               &  Smart Wearable Health Systems and Applications\\
TUGT                &    Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
USB                 &  Universal Serial Bus\\
USUST               &  Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\
WEFAPS          &  Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &    World Health Organization\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks good! I can use this for the list of abbreviations as well as for the list of symbols?

Comment: The reason why I accepted the other answer is that your version is not really well aligned...

Comment: You can use it for anything you want, it's just like a tabular environment.

...And regarding the alignment, you can also play with it by changing the parameters next to `\begin{longtable}{}`.  This is all very well explained in the `longtable` documentation that I pointed you out.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the length of your symbol descriptions, a regular list is also an option. Here's a list created with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) that breaks mid-paragraph if needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newlist{listofsymbols}{itemize}{1}
\SetLabelAlign{symbolleft}{\makebox[5em][r]{#1~:~}}
\setlist[listofsymbols]{
  before = {\section*{List of Symbols}},
  align = symbolleft,
  itemindent = -5em,
  leftmargin = !,
  labelwidth = 0pt,
  labelsep = 0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{listofsymbols}
  \item[Symbol1] Meaning of Symbol1
  \item[Symbol2] \lipsum[1-3]
  \item[Symboln] \lipsum[1]
  \item[Symbolz] Meaning of Symbolz
\end{listofsymbols}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you should fiddle with the `listofsymbols` length parameters inside `\setlist` so that it suits your needs.

Comment: I have used your function with the following result: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3630/i3kzov8r_png.htm
It seems not really well aligned, I tried to indicate it in the plot.

Comment: @RStudent: I've adjusted the use of `leftmargin = !` in my answer code. Your misalignment is to be expected, and you need to adjust the **two** lengths `5em` (one in the `\SetLabelAlign` and one in `itemindent`) to suit *your* setup. I've guessed that the maximum width would be `5em`, but it may not be; if you have longer/wider entries, use something like `7em`. [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) also provides `widest` as a key-value, but with `\SetLabelAlign` in the way I've used it, it's not really useful.

Comment: How to make hyperlink to this symbols and abbreviations

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: Try [this example](https://pastebin.com/2vDbGVWr).